# Inverse of a complicated matrix not working in Sympy/ Python

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, tensor

So I was trying to formulate some matrix out of another matrix's elements using sympy. But while the taking the inverse it didn't work I believe cause of the complicity of the matrix I am taking the inverse of.

```
x0, x1, x2, x3 = smp.symbols('x^0 x^1 x^2 x^3')
COORDS = [x0, x1, x2, x3]
N = len(COORDS)
g00 = smp.Function('g00')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g01 = smp.Function('g01')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g02 = smp.Function('g02')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g03 = smp.Function('g03')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g10 = smp.Function('g10')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g11 = smp.Function('g11')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g12 = smp.Function('g12')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g13 = smp.Function('g13')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g20 = smp.Function('g20')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g21 = smp.Function('g21')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g22 = smp.Function('g22')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g23 = smp.Function('g23')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g30 = smp.Function('g30')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g31 = smp.Function('g31')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g32 = smp.Function('g_32')(x0, x1, x2, x3)
g33 = smp.Function('g_33')(x0, x1, x2, x3)

g = smp.Matrix([[g00,g01,g02,g03],[g10,g11,g12,g13],[g20,g21,g22,g23],[g30,g31,g32,g33]])
```

and when I do `g.inv()` the kernel just doesn't finish. What should I do in order to take this matrix's inverse? Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: I see a lot of `g12` variables, but no `g`

Comment: Inverting a complete symbolic 4x4 matrix is an extremely complicated expression. See also [Sympy and Numpy unable to inverse matrix created using Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530760/12046409) and an example of how an [inverted 3x3 matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72051411/12046409) quickly gets messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully symbolic matrix has a complicated expression for its inverse (shown below). Feel free to substitute whatever you like for the entries of the matrix but it's unlikely that you can do anything useful with such an expression.

Here is the inverse of a fully symbolic 4x4 matrix (computed in less than a second):

```
In [8]: from sympy import *

In [9]: from sympy.polys.matrices import DomainMatrix

In [10]: dm = DomainMatrix.from_Matrix(Matrix(symbols('x:16')).reshape(4, 4))

In [11]: dm.to_field().inv().to_Matrix()
Out[11]: 
⎡                                                                             
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⎢-x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉
⎢                                                                             
⎢                                                                             
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⎢-x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉
⎢                                                                             
⎢                                                                             
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⎢-x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉
⎢                                                                             
⎢                                                                             
⎢─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⎣-x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉

                                                                       -x₁₀⋅x₁
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                       x₁₀⋅x₁₂
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                        x₁₁⋅x₁
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                        -x₁₀⋅x
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x

₃⋅x₇ + x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉           
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x
                                                                              
⋅x₇ - x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈            
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x
                                                                              
₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₅⋅x₈             
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x
                                                                              
₁₂⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₄ + x₁₂⋅x₆⋅x₉ - x₁₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₅⋅x₈            
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ 

                                                                              
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────
- x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────
- x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────
- x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────
- x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + 

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + 
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + 

                                                     -x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄ 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ +
                                                                              
                                                     x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄ -
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ +
                                                                              
                                                      x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₉ -
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ +
                                                                              
                                                      -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₉ 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ +

+ x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₉ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₉                             
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ 
                                                                              
 x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₈ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₈                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ 
                                                                              
 x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₈ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₉ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₈                               
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ 
                                                                              
+ x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₈ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₈                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ 

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
- x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
- x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
- x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
- x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x

                                                                              
─────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀
                                                                              
                                                                              
─────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀
                                                                              
                                                                              
─────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀
                                                                              
                                                                              
─────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁

                                     -x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇ - x₁₃⋅
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁
                                                                              
                                     x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇ + x₁₂⋅x
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁
                                                                              
                                     -x₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁
                                                                              
                                     x₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ - x₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁

x₃⋅x₆ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅                                                 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
₃⋅x₆ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄                                                  
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄                                                 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x
                                                                              
₄⋅x₄ + x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄                                                  
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅

                                                                              
───────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
───────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈  -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₃⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₆ - x₀⋅x

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₉ - x₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₁₅⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x

                    x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₇ - x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₆ - x₁₀⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₁⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ +
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅
                                                                              
                    -x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₇ + x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₆ + x₁₀⋅x₃⋅x₄ - x₁₁⋅x₂⋅x₄ + x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅
                                                                              
                     -x₀⋅x₁₁⋅x₅ + x₀⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ +
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅
                                                                              
                     x₀⋅x₁₀⋅x₅ - x₀⋅x₆⋅x₉ - x₁⋅x₁₀⋅x₄ + x₁⋅x₆⋅x₈ + x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₆ + x₁⋅x₁₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₄ - x₁⋅x₁₄⋅x₇⋅x₈ + x₁⋅x₁₅⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₀⋅x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₅ + x₁₀⋅

 x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉                                                                     
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅
                                                                              
- x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈                                                                    
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅
                                                                              
 x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈                                                                     
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅
                                                                              
x₂⋅x₅⋅x₈                                                                      
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₄ + x₁₁⋅x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₅ - x₁₁⋅x₁₃⋅x₂⋅x₄ - x₁₂⋅x₂⋅x₇⋅x₉ + x₁₂⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₉ + x₁₃⋅

                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅
                                                                              
                                                                              
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
x₂⋅x₇⋅x₈ - x₁₃⋅x₃⋅x₆⋅x₈ - x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₄⋅x₉ + x₁₄⋅x₃⋅x₅⋅x₈ + x₁₅⋅x₂⋅x₄⋅x₉ - x₁₅⋅x₂⋅

     ⎤
─────⎥
x₅⋅x₈⎥
     ⎥
     ⎥
─────⎥
x₅⋅x₈⎥
     ⎥
     ⎥
─────⎥
x₅⋅x₈⎥
     ⎥
     ⎥
─────⎥
x₅⋅x₈⎦
```